# Azure traffic manager route by URL pattern

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager, azure-application-gateway

We have web apps hosted on two data centers for high availability and we used traffic manager with round robin routing method to route traffic to either of the two data centers.

Now per business requirement, we need route the traffic by URL pattern. Say, for url /api/v1, route to data center 1, for url /api/v2, route to data center 2.

I know traffic manager does not support url based routing. Any workaround?

Comment: There's no specific workaround - you'd have to come up with your own. Possibly by splitting your site across multiple TLDs? Possibly by using a 3rd party traffic routing service? Unfortunately no single right answer to this.

Comment: Thanks David. I also checked Application Gateway which support url based routing. I am wondering whether it is practical to use application gateway to route traffic to different regions? Since Application gateway itself must be created in a given region.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Traffic Manager operates at the DNS layer and as such does not know any details about the URL related to the DNS request it receives - therefore URL based routing is not possible with Azure Traffic Manager. I encourage you to consider using Azure Application Gateway for URL based routing within a single region. For inter-region routing based on URLs, you could consider making the subdomains different and using DNS layer routing.